# Error 405 al enviar variable con un Select

Tags: php

Tengo mi codigo con un select que trae las variables de la base de datos, pero al momento de darle editar, me surge el error, pero curiosamente, es al momento de cambiarlo nada más.

```
    <select class="form-control" name='canon'>
        <option <?php if($fila1['canon']=='Bueno'){ echo "selected";}?> value="Bueno">Bueno</option>
        <option <?php if($fila1['canon']=='Regular'){ echo "selected";}?> value="Regular">Regular</option>
        <option <?php if($fila1['canon']=='Malo'){ echo "selected";}?> value="Malo">Malo</option>
    </select>
```

Este es mi código, pero lo curioso que es que tengo otros select con la misma dinámica, pero me funcionan perfecto, es esolo con estos select de las partes del arma, no se que hacer o en que puedo estar equivocandome.

Comment: Podrías poner el error que sale? nos ayudara bastante.

Comment: Hola Victor, mira, una ves selecciono cualquier opción a cambiar se demora en cargar y luego de varios minutos aparece: 
405 Not Allowed
nginx/1.14.1